# Scrape table using rvest - Embedded symbols/links

Tags: html, html-table, rvest, scrape

I tried to scrape the table on the following webpage: [http://www.comstats.de/squad/1-FC+Bayern+München](http://www.comstats.de/squad/1-FC+Bayern+M%C3%BCnchen)

My approach is successfull at first glance using the following code:

```
read_html("http://www.comstats.de/squad/1-FC+Bayern+München") %>% 
html_node("#inhalt > table.rangliste.autoColor.tablesorter.zoomable") %>%
html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

However, in the second column there are differing number of linked symbols which lead to a corrupt table having different number of elements (which is why there is need for fill = TRUE).

I was researching for hours... Who can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is searching for an answer to such questions as well: One possible solution is to use package htmltable (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmltab/vignettes/htmltab.html):

```
library(htmltab)

htmltab(doc = "http://www.comstats.de/squad/1-FC+Bayern+München", which = '//*[@id="inhalt"]/table[2]')
```